# Facebook android: Tracking friends real time location

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to develop an application that will give my friends real time location. Is it possible to use the graph API to update their current location (latitude and longitude). If not what is the best way to store and retrieve their latitude and longitude.

I got my friends latitude and longitude using the following FQL Query:

SELECT current_location.latitude,current_location.longitude FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND current_location

Also I wrote a code that will give the user real time location (latitude and longitude). But I need to find a way to store these info so I can use the graph API to get each friend info.

Comment: do u get any solution , please share which API YOU USE

Comment: I used the graph API to get users location according to their last check-in.